# Console Hangs when Attempting to Deploy Software Updates

Tags: sccm-2012

When in the SCCM 2012 console under Software Updates, I click Deploy on a Software Update Group and the console hangs indefinitely. It just stops; I click away and back and Windows does not recognize that the console has stopped responding. I end up having to kill the console through Task Manager. I have left the console for hours and it never becomes responsive again.

I have tried removing and reinstalling the SUP, without success. Server reboots do not help, either. The issue with the console occurs both on my desktop, and directly on the site server itself.

Any ideas? I've checked server logs and found nothing that would be indicative of a problem.

**Update:**
I managed to find something from the SMSAdminUI.log file. CA100065 is a deployment package that I created prior to attempting to deploy the software update group. This happens regardless of which package I point it at.

```
[1, PID:820][10/12/2012 08:59:26] :Disposed ResultObject was passed to update delegate, ignoring but refresh operation may not complete correctly
[14, PID:820][10/12/2012 13:53:57] :System.Management.ManagementException\r\nNot found \r\n   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.Initialize(Boolean getObject)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_wbemObject()
   at System.Management.PropertyData.RefreshPropertyInfo()
   at System.Management.PropertyDataCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.WqlConnectionManager.GetInstance(String objectPath)\r\nManagementException details:
instance of __ExtendedStatus
{
    Operation = "GetObject";
    ParameterInfo = "SMS_PackageToContent.ContentID=16794374,PackageID=\"CA100065\"";
    ProviderName = "WinMgmt";
};
\r\n
[14, PID:820][10/12/2012 13:53:57] :(SMS_PackageToContent.ContentID=16794374,PackageID='CA100065') does not exist or its IsContentValid returns false. We will (re)download this content.
[14, PID:820][10/12/2012 13:54:01] :Successfully validated or downloaded update fcadb0ea-90ce-4aad-bc95-192450f05211!
[14, PID:820][10/12/2012 13:54:02] :System.Management.ManagementException\r\nNot found \r\n   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.Initialize(Boolean getObject)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_wbemObject()
   at System.Management.PropertyData.RefreshPropertyInfo()
   at System.Management.PropertyDataCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.WqlConnectionManager.GetInstance(String objectPath)\r\nManagementException details:
instance of __ExtendedStatus
{
    Operation = "GetObject";
    ParameterInfo = "SMS_PackageToContent.ContentID=16787459,PackageID=\"CA100065\"";
    ProviderName = "WinMgmt";
};
\r\n
[14, PID:820][10/12/2012 13:54:02] :(SMS_PackageToContent.ContentID=16787459,PackageID='CA100065') does not exist or its IsContentValid returns false. We will (re)download this content.
[14, PID:820][10/12/2012 13:54:03] :Successfully validated or downloaded update eec264ac-fbc7-4cc4-891b-7cc6ab5bfe0e!
[14, PID:820][10/12/2012 13:54:03] :System.Management.ManagementException\r\nNot found \r\n   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.Initialize(Boolean getObject)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_wbemObject()
   at System.Management.PropertyData.RefreshPropertyInfo()
   at System.Management.PropertyDataCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.WqlConnectionManager.GetInstance(String objectPath)\r\nManagementException details:
instance of __ExtendedStatus
{
    Operation = "GetObject";
    ParameterInfo = "SMS_PackageToContent.ContentID=16784547,PackageID=\"CA100065\"";
    ProviderName = "WinMgmt";
};
\r\n
[14, PID:820][10/12/2012 13:54:03] :(SMS_PackageToContent.ContentID=16784547,PackageID='CA100065') does not exist or its IsContentValid returns false. We will (re)download this content.
[14, PID:820][10/12/2012 13:54:05] :Successfully validated or downloaded update 8d780338-eec1-4d31-b1cd-6187400c02f3!
[14, PID:820][10/12/2012 13:54:05] :System.Management.ManagementException\r\nNot found \r\n   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObject.Initialize(Boolean getObject)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_wbemObject()
   at System.Management.PropertyData.RefreshPropertyInfo()
   at System.Management.PropertyDataCollection.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.GetPropertyValue(String propertyName)
   at System.Management.ManagementBaseObject.get_Item(String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.ManagementProvider.WqlQueryEngine.WqlConnectionManager.GetInstance(String objectPath)\r\nManagementException details:
instance of __ExtendedStatus
{
    Operation = "GetObject";
    ParameterInfo = "SMS_PackageToContent.ContentID=16787423,PackageID=\"CA100065\"";
    ProviderName = "WinMgmt";
};
\r\n
[14, PID:820][10/12/2012 13:54:05] :(SMS_PackageToContent.ContentID=16787423,PackageID='CA100065') does not exist or its IsContentValid returns false. We will (re)download this content.
```

Answer (score -1):

This could be just poor console performance, it does happen especially in larger environments where the console is fairly slow.

I posted an article on my blog some time ago about improving console performance, can I suggest you look into it and give it a go? You might be surprised at the difference it makes. Here is the link to the article... http://martyncoupland.co.uk/2014/01/improving-console-performance-in-system-center-consoles/

As a bit of background, we are setting the MAXDOP setting within SQL, this is due to how queries against the database are issued in Configuration Manager.

Comment: ...and with the link broken, this answer is now useless.